# How should I rewrite the code so that Spring automatically inject components into the class constructor?

Tags: java, spring

Studying Spring and stumbled upon difficulties. How to inject beans through the constructor or through fields?
I learned to do this through XML configuration, but it does not work through annotations.
Here is my code.
Interface Music:

```
public interface Music {
    public String playMusic();
}
```

Class FolkMusic:

```
@Component
public class FolkMusic implements Music {
   @Override
   public String playMusic() {
       System.out.println("FOLK");
       return null;
   }
}
```

Class HipHipMusic:

```
@Component
public class HipHopMusic implements Music {
    @Override
    public String playMusic() {
        System.out.println("HipHop");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Class MusicPlayer:

```
@Component
public class MusicPlayer {
    ArrayList<Music> mu;
    @Autowired
    public MusicPlayer(ArrayList arrayList){
        mu = arrayList;
    }
    public void playMusic(){
        System.out.println("Size = " + mu.size());
    }
}
```

Search for components in XML:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="cam.mark.mus"/>
```

How should I rewrite the code so that Spring automatically inject components into the MusicPlayer class constructor?
With this code, no errors appear in the console. The result is displayed "Size = 0"

Comment: Have you tried adding the generic `Music ` argument to the constructors list parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `List` instead of `ArrayList`. Also make sure that you are passing `List<Music>` not `List` in the constructor.

`MusicPlayer` should look like this:

```
@Component
public class MusicPlayer {

    List<Music> mu;

    public MusicPlayer(List<Music> arrayList) {
        mu = arrayList;
    }

    public void playMusic() {
        System.out.println("Size = " + mu.size());
    }
}
```

You can omit the `@Autowired` on the constructor because there's only one constructor.